# Use first element from list of tuples as dictionary key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How can I take a list of tuples like the following:

```
test = [('A', 1, 8, 4), ('B', 2, 6, 2), ('C', 3, 6, 2)]
```

And make a dictionary that uses the first element in each tuple as the key

```
output = {'A': (1, 8, 4), 'B':(2, 6, 2), 'C': (3, 6, 2)}
```

If the original list was a list of tuples of length two, then `dict(test)` would have worked fine, but that does not work in this case.

I could do `[i[0] for i in test]` to extract the first element of each tuple, but I was thinking there is probably a more efficient/Pythonic and generalizable way of doing this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
output = {item[0]: item[1:] for item in test}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dict`

**Ex:**

```
test = [('A', 1, 8, 4), ('B', 2, 6, 2), ('C', 3, 6, 2)]
print( dict((i[0], i[1:]) for i in test) )
```

**Output:**

```
{'A': (1, 8, 4), 'C': (3, 6, 2), 'B': (2, 6, 2)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could expand on your proposed answer and do an dictionary comprehension instead. Try something along these lines:

```
output = {i[0]: i[1:] for i in test}
```